# How to use ocserv docker container on a server which already connected to another VPN?

Tags: docker, vpn, docker-network, ocserv

I have a docker container of ocserv on my server, I can connect to it using openconnect client from other devices without any problem. but when my server have been connected to another VPN itself using openconnect client, I can't connect to it anymore because VPN route all traffic trough the tunnel.

I couldn't even ssh to my server but I used this rules:

```
ip rule add table 128 from x.x.x.x
ip route add table 128 to x.x.x.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via x.x.x.1
```

and now I can ssh to my server but I still can't use ocserv.